# Memory leak when running mxnet cpu inference

Tags: python, mxnet

I tested 100 pictures and the analysis of memory_profiler is listed below. Why does line 308 cause a lot of memory growth?

mxnet==1.5.1

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   297 8693.719 MiB   81.809 MiB           data = nd.array(im_tensor)
   298 8693.719 MiB    0.000 MiB           db = mx.io.DataBatch(data=(data,), provide_data=[('data', data.shape)])
   299 8630.039 MiB    2.840 MiB           self.model.forward(db, is_train=False)
   300 8630.039 MiB    2.320 MiB           net_out = self.model.get_outputs()
   301 8693.719 MiB    2.062 MiB           for _idx,s in enumerate(self._feat_stride_fpn):
   302 8693.719 MiB    2.062 MiB               _key = 'stride%s'%s
   303 8693.719 MiB    1.031 MiB               stride = int(s)
   304 8693.719 MiB    1.031 MiB               if self.use_landmarks:
   305 8693.719 MiB    1.031 MiB                 idx = _idx*3
   306                                         else:
   307                                           idx = _idx*2
   308 8693.719 MiB 4700.676 MiB               scores = net_out[idx].asnumpy()
   309 8693.719 MiB    1.289 MiB               print scores.shape
   310 8693.719 MiB    1.031 MiB               scores = scores[:, self._num_anchors['stride%s'%s]:, :, :]
   311 8693.719 MiB    1.031 MiB               idx+=1
   312 8693.719 MiB    2.836 MiB               bbox_deltas = net_out[idx].asnumpy()
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MXNet python API calls are actually just queued in the MXNet backend engine and processed asynchronously in C++. So what you see in this python profiler may not reflect what is actually happening under the hood. For profiling I recommend you to look at dedicated tools: https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/tutorials/performance/backend/profiler.html

I suspect your `.asnumpy()` call is associated with high memory usage because it is a blocking call: it requires immediate availability of results and consequently forces the mxnet engine to compute necessary dependencies immediately. It is generally recommended to **avoid using Numpy in MXNet code** and use [`MXNet NDArray`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/docs/api/ndarray/index.html) instead, which is more appropriate for deep learning (asynchronous, GPU-compatible, support for automatic differentiation) than Numpy. For example you could accumulate any info you need in an `MXNet NDArray` and then do whatever you need with it at the end of the execution (save to file, convert to Numpy, etc). More resources:

- [Common tips regarding Numpy vs NDArray in MXNet](https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/tutorials/packages/ndarray/gotchas_numpy_in_mxnet.html)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010593/mxnet-gradient-descent-for-linear-regression-variable-types-error/) provides a summary of differences vs Numpy and MXNet NDArray